# how to remove content of text file in android

Tags: android, string, file, file-handling

Here is my code to store a text file in the internal memory. The file name is pass.txt and stores "0000".

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;//
        try {

            fileOutputStream=openFileOutput("pass.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write("0000".getBytes());


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("pass", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("pass", e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            if(fileOutputStream!=null)
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("pass", e.toString());
                }
        }
```

I want to remove "0000" from the file and write "1234" in it programmatically.  Please help me. "1234" is stored in a `String` variable.

Comment: Just use the same cide and replace "0000" by "1234". Or use String string="1234"; write(string.getBytes());.

Comment: if(pass.getText().toString().equals(cpass.getText().toString()))
            {
               
            }

Comment: if(pass.getText().toString().equals(cpass.getText().toString()))
            {
                 
            }    here in b/w if statment plz can u write the code to do so